# Running webpack with powershell in VSTS

Tags: powershell, webpack, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40426489/running-webpack-in-vsts-tfs-cannot-find-webpack) post as a starting point I followed the basic steps outlined there.

1. Install webpack on the agent
2. Get the install path for webpack
3. Run webpack from the exact install path

I've tested this locally and it the script works fine. Once I put it on VSTS as part of a build (just a powershell task on an agent) it works up until I execute the webpack commands where it returns nothing. No output whatsoever.

```
Write-Host `nInstalling webpack and webpack-command
npm install --no-save --no-package-lock -g webpack webpack-command

Write-Host `nGetting the environment variables for webpack
(Get-Item -Path ".\" -Verbose).FullName
$env:Path = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","Machine") + ";" + [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","User")
$webpackOptions = Get-Command -CommandType Application -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Name webpack | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Definition

Write-Host `nThe options:
$webpackOptions | Write-Host

Write-Host `nSelected:
$webpack = $webpackOptions -Match 'cmd' | Select-Object -First 1
Write-Host $webpack

# On the build agent it is at this point that I get blank results
# On my local machine I get the paths such as:
#    C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\webpack.cmd --config webpack.css.config.js
# The results of webpack running
Write-Host `nPacking webpack.config.cs
Write-Host $webpack --config webpack.config.js
& $webpack --config webpack.config.js

# Same as above
Write-Host `nPacking webpack.css.config.cs
Write-Host $webpack --config webpack.css.config.js
& $webpack --config webpack.css.config.js
```

Does anyone have any ideas? This is particularly strange to me as when I print the `selected` path for webpack it seems to find the value I'd expect, that is it prints `C:\npm\prefix\webpack.cmd`

Comment: So, just for future reference for anyone looking at this. I actually worked around this by simply using npm to run webpack. I `npm installed --dev webpack webpack-command` and, as a script in package.json, I called both configs `"build-prod": "webpack -p --config 1 && "webpack -p --config 2""`. On the build server I ran an `npm install` step and a custom step `run build-prod`. While I had to work around it a bit it's a lot better than the powershell script, so I guess that was how I should have done it to begin with.(the above code blocks are psedo-code)

Comment: You can write the solution as answer and accept it. And it can help other member get the solution more clearly :)

Comment: @MarinaLiuMSFT I wasn't sure if I wanted to have it as the answer or not, since I'm not really answering my question I'm simply offering a work around (although I'm being awfully pedantic drawing that distinction). I'll add the answer at least because the formatting will be more clear, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

I have a work around where I am using `npm` and `package.json` to run the scripts and install the dependencies.

1. `npm install webpack webpack-cli --save-dev` - these are the dependencies you need to run webpack, you can swap `webpack-cli` with `webpack-command` which is apparently lighter weight if you want

   - This is done locally, not as a build step. Check it in when the package.json is updated.
2. Create your build step in your `package.json`. I created two: `build` and `build-prod`
3. Create two npm steps in your vsts build.

   - The first is just an `npm install` to install all your packages
   - The second is a custom step to run your package.json script. In my case the text is `run build-prod`

That's it!

---

The `package.json` with the two scripts I have to call webpack:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js && webpack --config webpack.2.config.js",
    "build-prod": "webpack -p --config webpack.config.js && webpack -p --config webpack.2.config.js"
  }
  ...
}
```

And, finally a picture of the tasks.

[image]